# Default font in pre-lollipop devices when using appcompat widgets in Android

Tags: android

I understand that that Material design enforces Roboto by default when you load **san-serif fonts** in the UI widgets.

I also understand in order to render material design in pre-lollipop one needs appcompat UI widgets.

**Do this imply that these appcompat UI widgets will render Roboto in pre-lolipop devices as well?**

Comment: I don't think that it works identically on all devices. Roboto is changing and looks different on different platforms. Not all platforms have all versions of Roboto. Pre-4.0 devices have Droid instead of Roboto and Noto. Fonts are quite heavy addition to libraries. Due to that I would imagine that you have to provide your own .ttf files to have consistent look on all platforms. Anyone who can verify that?

Answer (score 1):

No, the font on pre-L is not Roboto.

you can use Libraries such as [RobotoTextView](https://github.com/johnkil/Android-RobotoTextView), which is quite nice and easy to use, to set all of your text widgets to Roboto.

Comment: You should mark the answer correct if it solved your problem :-)